# Как вы создаете спрайты на Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack2, спрайт

Всем привет, как вы генерируете спрайты на webpack ? Какие плагины используете ?

Comment: spritesmith? Как на этот вопрос вообще отвечать прикажете?